# Proper way to write a spring-batch ItemReader

Tags: spring-batch, autowired

I'm constructing a spring-batch job that modifies a given number of records. The list of record ID's are an input parameter of the job. For example, one job might be: Modify the record Id's {1,2,3,4} and set parameters X and Y on related tables.

Since I'm unable to pass a potentialy very long input list (tipical cases, 50K records) to my ItemReader I only pass a MyJobID which then the itemReader uses to load the target ID list.

Problem is, the resulting code appears "wrong" (altough it works) and not in the spirit of spring-batch. Here's the reader:

```
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@Component
public class MyItemReader implements ItemReader<Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private JobService jobService;
    private List<Integer> itemsList;
    private Long jobId;

    @Autowired
    public MyItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['jobId']}") final Long jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.itemsList = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        // First pass: Load the list.
        if (itemsList == null) {
            itemsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            MyJob myJob = (MyJob) jobService.loadById(jobId);

            for (Integer i : myJob.getTargedIdList()) {
                itemsList.add(i);
            }
        }

        // Serve one at a time:
        if (itemsList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return itemsList.remove(0);
        }
    }   
}
```

I tried to move the first part of the read() method to the constructor but the @Autowired reference is null at that point. Afterwards (on the read method) it's initialized.

Is there a better way to write the ItemReader? I would like to move the "load"Or is this the best solution for this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Show me code of jobService.loadById(), I will come back with feedbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, your approach is not "wrong", but probably not ideal.

Firstly, you could move the initialisation to a initMethod which is annotated with @PostConstruct. This method is called after all Autowired fields have been injected:

```
@PostConstruct 
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    itemsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    MyJob myJob = (MyJob) jobService.loadById(jobId);

    for (Integer i : myJob.getTargedIdList()) {
        itemsList.add(i);
    }
}
```

But there is still the problem, that you load all the data at once. If you have a billion records to process, this could blow up the memory.

So what you should do is to load only a chunk of your data into memory, then return the items one by one in your read method. If all entries of a chunk have been returned, load the next chunk and return its items one by one again. If there is no other chunk to be loaded, then return null from the read method.

This ensures that you have a constant memory footprint regardless of how many records you have to process.
(If you have a look at FlatFileItemReader, you see that it uses a BufferedReader to read the data from the disk. While it has nothing to do with SpringBatch, it is the same principle: it reads a chunk of data from the disk, returns that and if more data is needed, it reads the next chunk of data).

Next problem is the restartability. What happens if the job crashes after doing 90% of the work? How can the job be restarted and only process the missing 10%?
This is actually a feature that springbatch provides, all you have to do is to implement the ItemStream interface and implement the methods open(), update(), close().

If you consider this two points - load data in chunks instead all at once and implement ItemStream interface - you'll end up having a reader that is in the spring spirit.